# Why is disk IO on my new AWS EC2 instance so much slower?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, disk, amazon-ami, disk-io

I have a regular EC2 instance `A` with a 200GB SSD filled with data. I used this disk to create an AMI and used that AMI to spin up another EC2 instance `B` with the same specs.

`B` started almost instantaneously which surprised me since I thought there would be a delay while AWS copies my 200GB EBS to the SSD corresponding to the new instance. However I noticed IO is extremely slow on `B`. It takes 3x as long to parse data on `B`.

Why is this, and how can I overcome this? It's too slow for my application which requires fast disk IO.

Comment: Can you please add the EC2 instance configuration details for your EC2 instances A and B?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because a newly-created EBS volume [is built from S3 on-demand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-restoring-volume.html): when EC2 first reads a block from that volume it's retrieved from S3. You only get the "full" EBS performance once all blocks have been loaded. This is a huge problem, btw, for big databases restored from snapshot.

One solution may be [fast snapshot restore](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-ebs-fast-snapshot-restore-fsr/). Although the docs don't describe what's happening behind the scenes, my guess is that they do a parallel disk copy from an existing EBS image. However, you will pay $0.75 per hour per snapshot, and are limited to 10 restores per hour.

Given the use-case that you described in another question, I think that the best solution is to keep an on-demand instance that you start and stop for your job. Assuming you're using Linux, you are charged per-second, so if you only run for 10-20 minutes out of the hour, you'll pay a pro-rated price. And unlike spot instances, you'll know that the machine will always be available and always be able to finish the job.

Another alternative is to just leave the spot instance running. If you're running for a significant portion of every hour, you're not really saving that much by shutting the instance down.

Comment: Is it possible to create an EC2 spot instance using a gp SSD that I've pre-loaded with all the data? So the data is immediately available locally unlike with an AMI that needs to be transferred from S3?

Comment: You could prebuild an EBS volume that you attach to the instance after startup. You would pass the volume ID to the instance in user-data, and have a script that attaches and mounts it.

Comment: I know this can be done with regular EC2 instances but can it also be done with spot instances? Will the disk IO be quick immediately after startup, unlike when it's created using a large AMI?